# Regrouping lines of a text file

Tags: python, sorting

I am using a Python script to generate some Stata commands. The output is a text file. I would like to group lines belonging to a same observation, which is currently not the case, using Python.

A typical line in this file (let's call it file.txt) is of the sort:

```
[something something] if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & [other things]
```

Where a, b and c are identifying variables. An (a,b,c) triplets uniquely identifies an observation. What I am trying to do is to sort file.txt by grouping all lines related to a same observation together.

For instance, go from:

```
replace k = 1 if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & comments_1 == "I wish I was better at Python"

replace k = 2 if a == 1 & b == 3 & c == 4 & comments_1 == ""

replace g = "Example" if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & comments_1 == "I wish I was better at Python"
```

to:

```
replace k = 1 if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & comments_1 == "I wish I was better at Python"


replace g = "Example" if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & comments_1 == "I wish I was better at Python"


replace k = 2 if a == 1 & b == 3 & c == 4 & comments_1 == ""
```

The lines 1 and 3 of the input are next to each other in the output because they relate to the same observation (the same a, b, c triplet). This is different from sorting alphabetically, so I cannot use sort().

My plan would be:

> Create an empty dictionary dict[tuple[int]:set[str]]
>
> Read each line of the text file. For each line, get the triplet by searching for the characters after 'a == ' and before ' b ==' and so forth.
>
> If the triplet is in the dictionary, add the line as a string in the set to which the triplet points to. If not, create the entry and add the string.
>
> For each string in the set of each entry, write in a file the strings.

This I believe would sort the file.

Would that work? Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me. You could use a regex to extract the observations. For example, assuming that observations are made up of positive integers you could use:

```
import re
line = 'replace k = 1 if a == 1 & b == 2 & c == 3 & comments_1 == "test"'
m = re.search(r'a == (\d+) & b == (\d+) & c == (\d+)', line)
observation = tuple(map(int, m.groups()))
print(observation)
```

This prints the tuple `(1, 2, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good approach, but since you want to retain all lines, I wouldn't bother grouping lines with the same triple: Just make a list of all lines and sort them with their value triple as the sort key.

```
def getvalues(line):
    """Extract a value triple from a line that matches the pattern"""
    m = re.search(r"if a == (\d+) & b == (\d+) & c == (\d+) &", line)
    if m:
        return tuple(int(v) for v in m.groups())
    else:
        return line   # Lines that don't match the pattern are sorted normally

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

lines.sort(key=getvalues)
```

The above assumes that all lines have identical variable names, white space, etc. If not, you'll need to elaborate your regexp.